# Input for date with empty value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, input, datepicker

I have input for date :

```
<label for="search-startDate">From:</label>
<input type="text" name="startDate" id="search-startDate" data-date-format="mm/dd/y" ng-model="requestSearch.startDate" placeholder="From Date" ui-date value="" />
```

In controller I have property :

```
$scope.requestSearch = new Object();

$scope.requestSearch.startDate = new Date();
```

Currently with this all Input has predefined value `new Date()` which is Current Date, even if I set `value=""`.

How can I make predefined value to be empty?

I've tried to set `$scope.requestSearch.startDate` to empty string or `null` but this throw error, cause on page load I made request to server with this property to Json like `$scope.requestSearch.startDate.toJSON().slice(0, 10)`

---

**UPD** Another problem - when I set empty string or null to property I get error

```
ng-Model value must be a Date object - currently it is a string - use ui-date-format to convert it from a string
```

as I use date-format.

So currently I am trying to omit this error somehow. Logic is fine.

Comment: If you're using slice(0, 10), then obviously it would raise TypeError since it is trying to slice a empty or null value

Comment: Why do you want to `toJSON()` a null/empty value on page load?  Because `ngModel` is two-way binding, you cannot have the UI display an empty value when the model has a value; vice versa.

Comment: @ManiKandan and @KKKKKKKK Ok. I am agree. But if I set empty string to property than I get error `ng-Model value must be a Date object - currently it is a string - use ui-date-format to convert it from a string`. So property should be a Date. If Date - that it has some non-empty value...